# PDFKit: Page Indicator Not Showing When Scrolling Multi-Page PDF in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, uikit, pdfkit

I am using PDFKit to display PDF documents in my iOS application. The page indicator is not showing when I scroll through multi-page PDFs, like with pdf in Files for example (see attachment)

[image]

Didn't find any property that controls that

Comment: Daniel don’t forget to award the answer to Ben.

Comment: Using WebKit instead is a better solution - you get it out of the box

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's something you have to do yourself, but it's not too hard. You need [`PDFViewDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfviewdelegate) so you can have[`PDFViewPageChanged`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification/name/1505038-pdfviewpagechanged) notifications to trigger the change in your custom label whenever the page changes, and you can customize your label however you want– obviously including the [`currentPage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfview/1504963-currentpage/).